# Will my Fn keys stop working if I reinstall my keyboard drivers?

Tags: laptop, drivers, keyboard, fn-key

My computer is an Acer Aspire M5-583-6428 laptop computer. Lately, I've been having a strange issue with my keyboard, which I've decided to attempt to fix by uninstalling my keyboard drivers and rebooting to reinstall them.

Like many current laptops, it has an <kbd>Fn</kbd> key which allows for additional functions to be performed easily. However, I'm worried that this will stop working if I mess with the keyboard drivers, and I am hesitant to reinstall them for this reason.

To sum it all up, will my <kbd>Fn</kbd> functions persist if I reinstall my laptop's keyboard drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the driver that you install has configurations for the function keys.

Comment: It can have configuration for those keys, depends on the keyboard, but most keyboards don't require specific keyboard driver beyond the generic drivers unless it has special capability ( i.e. macro keys ).

Comment: even if it did have custom configs, Windows would probably already know about it